# NDB: How to do a partial ancestor match?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Context:

I am working on a web app. 
If I don't use ancestors, trying to update a  element after immediately inserting a new value of a ndb.Model does not fetch the new value. 
Using ancestors though, I get the result consistently.

BUT, I want to make a hierarchy of items.

Example:

```
class Office(ndb.Expando):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Given the offices:

```
HQ = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0'), name='HQ')
BR1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0','Office', 'BR1'), name='Branch 1')
BR2 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR2'), name='Branch 2')
BR1S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', 'S1'), name='Branch 1 Sector 1')
BR1S2 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', 'S2'), name='Branch 1 Sector 2')
BR2S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', 'S1'), name='Branch 2, Sector 1')
BR2S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', 'S2'), name='Branch 2, Sector 2')
```

I can't get strong consistency, because they are all root ancestors.

Given the offices:

```
HQ = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0'), name='HQ')
BR1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0','Office', 'BR1'), name='Branch 1')
BR2 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR2'), name='Branch 2')
BR1S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR1','Office', 'S1'), name='Branch 1 Sector 1')
BR1S2 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR1','Office', 'S2'), name='Branch 1 Sector 2')
BR2S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR2','Office', 'S1'), name='Branch 2, Sector 1')
BR2S1 = Office(key=ndb.Key('Office', '0', 'Office', 'BR2','Office', 'S2'), name='Branch 2, Sector 2')
```

I also can't get them all from a single query, because the ancestor parameter only matches exactly.

I would like to query for the ancestor `ndb.Key('Office', '0', *)`, but haven't figured out how to do it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried an ancestor query? because it matches all children irrespective of depth.  Also if you have just inserted an entity, then you have the key, if you need to do a follow up update, why not fetch the item by key, then it will be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

See [Ancestor Querys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor)

```
key = ndb.Key(BlogPost, 12345)
qry = Comment.query(ancestor=key)
```

So your example is

```
key = ndb.Key(Office, 0)
qry = Office.query(ancestor=key)
```

Comment: THe problem is that this only works for the root ancestor. 
If I try `key = ndb.Key(Office, 'BR1')`, I get nothing.

Comment: ndb.Key(Office, 'BR1') is not an ancestor.  You really should re-read the docs on keys and what constitues an ancestor.  You are trying to match a bit of a key somewhere in a path, which can't be done.  If you want to do that, you need to store all the elements of the key (path) in a repeating key property and then query for the key in that property.